# Cloud function deployment issue - main.py file missing

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

When I zip my source code and deploy it to the cloud function - it is always complaining that main.py is missing. any way we can solve this problem if main.py is in a different python package instead of the root ?

```
project-repo/
      functions/
          - main.py 
      requirements.txt
```

i tried modifying --entry-file option with fully qualified name - but still didn't work

Answer (score 2):

There is no `--entry-file` for `gcloud deploy` as can be seen in the [documentations](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy).

You are supposed to set the `--entry-point`.

`gcloud functions deploy <function-name> --entry-point functions.main --runtime python<version> --trigger-http` assumes that the entry point file (named `main.py`) is located in the `functions` directory.